# Android Intent to open "Mass Storage Activity"

Tags: android, android-intent, usb-mass-storage

I need to open USB Mass Storage Activity from my application.

Is there any `Intent` to do this?

something like

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS))`

Comment: What do you mean by the "Mass Storage Activity"?  Do you mean the USB computer connection subsettings page that lets you select between MTP and PTP on ICS+ devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use following:

`su -c setprop sys.usb.config <command>`

Full list of  can be found by this one command:
`cat init.usb.rc`

Function to be able to run command from app:

```
   public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
            for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                    os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
            }           
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
            os.flush();
}
```