# How to navigate to android USB Mass Storage Activity?

Tags: android, navigation, usb-mass-storage

I would like to get USB Mass Storage activity to turn on or off the usb mode when device is connected to pc.I have implemented an application as follows.

```
public class USB_ConnectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.onButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!(Environment.MEDIA_SHARED.equals(state))) {

                //How to navigate android USB Mass Storage page

            }
        }
    });


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.offButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((Environment.MEDIA_SHARED.equals(state))) {

                //How to navigate android USB Mass Storage page

            }

        }
    });

        }
   }
```

from the above code I have used two buttons for turn off and on usb mass storage.But I don't have more information about it to navigate android in built USB Mass Storage page.
Please any body help me.

Comment: Its not possible.Android SDK dose not support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to launch the USB mass storage `Activity`, then your question is an exact duplicate of: [Android Intent to open "Mass Storage Activity"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652917) and should be closed.

If you actually want to *change* the status of the USB mode, which is what it looks like, then this isn't a duplicate (as far as I can tell), but the answer is still: you can't do it.

Maybe there's a better way, but when I want to know what Intents are available for launching system Activities, I look at the Android SDK documentation for [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and search for "activity action".  That shows you many system Activities you can launch, such as the "battery use" `Activity` and the uninstallation `Activity`.  There's nothing there showing the USB mode `Activity` as a public `Intent`.  Excusing the pun, this was probably intentional.

And there's certainly no documentation I can find about any way to programmatically turn USB mode on or off, and this is also presumably intentional.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from the Android SDK.

Comment: Explaining why would help, perhaps you could expand your answer?